# React Tornado websockets mongodb multi user app

Tags: django, mongodb, reactjs, websocket, tornado

I have a giant Django app( with multiple modules), where we map the actors with their movies, movies with their , map actors with their wikipedia info/ IMDB info and so on. When multiple users try to map/curate stuffs, users update on same actors and the data. So we want to use Tornado, MongoDB(store), ReactJS front-end. Can some one give pointers on this?

Comment: Hi Ram, I also have a giant application using tornado + redis + angular, I use redis pub/sub modules with tornado websocket and ofcourse angular for frontend. What exactly is you approach and what kind of pointers are you looking for

Comment: Hi abhishek, Thanks for the reply. We almost have the same stack. Except angular it is react at my end, and instead of redis/redux my Lead wants to use MongoDB as the store. So for example, if there are 1000 actors to be mapped with their wikipedia bio - User1 logs in he looks at Morgan Freeman, then this information is sent from the client side (React) to Tornado which keeps listening async. Tornado persists in Mongo(Which maintains a Keyvalue store). So the same Mongo Collection is referenced in my Django Views which sends the API JSON to react.

Comment: Because of this the other users will not even see Morgan Freeman in their list, to do the curation. The flow should be React(Websocket) --> Tornado -- > Mongo --> Django filters the rest api of the actors list --> sends back to React. This will avoid, multiple updates to Morgan Freeman at the same time, as the users will not be able to see it at all.